# R kernel for jupyter dying --- can't find libzmq.so.4

Tags: r, anaconda

I'm using the Anaconda [R-essentials bundle](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/jupyter-and-conda-r).

Following the docs, I created a virtual env:

`conda create -n my-r-env -c r r-essentials`

I started a Jupyter notebook `ipython notebook --no-browser`.

I create a new R notebook (I see R in the dropdown below Python3).

But the kernel keeps dying and Jupyter is throwing the error:

`libzmq.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The directory it's looking in (`my-r-env/lib/R/library/rzmq/libs`) has `rzmq.so`.

But, not `libzmq.so.4`.

What's the right way to solve this?

Comment: See also https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/506. It seems like there is little interest in fixing this, though. For a quick and dirty workaround see the linked issue.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Ended up just using `rpy2` :)

Comment: I have the same problem and tried the suggestion of jmberros in link (`conda create -y -n rkernel-fix -c r r-essentials python=3.4 zeromq=4.0*`) but the R kernel is still dying. Is there any other recommended solution?

Comment: We recently switched to a different zmq package. You might try to install irkernel directly from github: `install_github("irkernel/repr"); install_github("irkernel/IRdisplay"); install_github("irkernel/IRkernel")` (the last will hopefully install the new zmq package from CRAN, otherwise you need to install that like any other package via `install.packages`).